# ¿Cómo generar excel con datos de mysql a partir de una consulta en php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7, phpexcel

Estoy trabajando con un archivo en php dónde hago registros a mysql y los visualizo directo en en el php, esto con la finalidad de editar y eliminar (CRUD).

La estructura es la siguiente:

```
ID  | CÓDIGO | EMPRESA | REPRESENTANTE | 
 1     15677     CORE     IRENE FUENTES     (Btn|GenerarExcel)
 2     11112    ROBLES    IGNACIO LÓPEZ     (Btn|GenerarExcel)
 3     12344    ZAPATOS   HUGO SÁNCHEZ      (Btn|GenerarExcel)
```

Me gustaría hacer un archivo php que genere un reporte excel a partir del dato (código) y me muestre los registros de otra tabla llamada "exámenes" que contengan todos los iguales al que se selecciono para generar que muestro aquí arriba, ejemplo:
Si presiono "BTN|GenerarEXCEL" del código 15677 haga la consulta de ese mismo pero en la tabla "examenes" de aquí abajo y genere mi excel.

```
ID  | CÓDIGO | RESPUESTA1 | RESPUESTA2 | RESPUESTA3 |
 1     15677        2            2            1         
 2     15677        2            2            2         
 3     12344        1            1            1
```

Estoy ocupando PHP Excel como librería pero acepto sugerencias.
Este es mi código CRUD:

```
 <body>
 <div class="container">
 <h2 style="text-align:center">Administrar Empresas Registradas</h2><br>
  <div class="row">        
  <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
  <b>Nombre: </b><input type="text" id="campo" name="campo" />
  <input type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-info" />
  </form>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>CODIGO</th>
          <th>EMPRESA</th>
          <th>REPRSENTANTE</th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['codigo']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['empresa']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['representante']; ?></td>
            <?php echo "<td><a href='modificar.php? id_empresa=".$row['id_empresa']."'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-success'>Modificar</button> </a></td>";?>
            <?php echo "<td><a href='eliminar.php?id_empresa=".$row['id_empresa']."'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>Eliminar</button> </a></td>";?>
            <td><a href="generarexcel.php"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" name="generarExcel">Evaluaciones</button> </a></span></a></td>
          </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
       </div>
       </div>
      </div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Eliminar Registro</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        ¿Desea eliminar este registro?
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Delete</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));

    $('.debug-url').html('Delete URL: <strong>' + $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href') + '</strong>');
  });
</script> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto a funcionado para mi, espero que para alguien más también:

```
 <?php
 if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
die('Este ejemplo sólo se puede ejecutar desde un navegador Web');

/** Incluye PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/excel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
// Crear nuevo objeto PHPExcel
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

 // Propiedades del documento
 $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator(" ")
                         ->setLastModifiedBy(" ")
                         ->setTitle(" ")
                         ->setSubject(" ")
                         ->setDescription(" ")
                         ->setKeywords(" ")
                         ->setCategory(" ");



  // Combino las celdas desde A1 hasta D1
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A1:AU');

  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'REPORTE DE CUESTIONARIOS')
        ->setCellValue('A2', 'CÓDIGO')
        ->setCellValue('B2', 'R1')
        ->setCellValue('C2', 'R2')
        ->setCellValue('D2', 'R3')


   // Fuente de la primera fila en negrita
   $boldArray = array('font' => array('bold' => true,),'alignment' => 
   array('horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER));

   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:E2')->applyFromArray($boldArray);       



   //Ancho de las columnas
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(10);   
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(7);    
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(7);    
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(7);    


  /*Extraer datos de MYSQL*/
    # conectare la base de datos
   $con=@mysqli_connect('localhost', 'myuser', 'mypsw', 'MYDB');
    if(!$con){
    die("imposible conectarse: ".mysqli_error($con));
    }
   if (@mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Connect failed: ".mysqli_connect_errno()." : ". mysqli_connect_error());
   }
   $sql="SELECT * FROM examenes  order by id_respuesta";
     $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
     $cel=3;//Numero de fila donde empezara a crear  el reporte
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $codigo=$row['codigo'];
    $r1=$row['r1'];
    $r2=$row['r2'];
    $r3=$row['r3'];

        // Agregar datos
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue($a, $codigo)
        ->setCellValue($b, $r1)
        ->setCellValue($c, $r2)
        ->setCellValue($d, $r3);

     $cel+=1;
    }

  /*Fin extracion de datos MYSQL*/
  $rango="A2:$e";
  $styleArray = array('font' => array( 'name' => 'Arial','size' => 10),
 'borders'=>array('allborders'=>array('style'=> 
  PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,'color'=>array('argb' => 'FFF')))
  );
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($rango)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
  // Cambiar el nombre de hoja de cálculo
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Reporte de cuestionarios');


  // Establecer índice de hoja activa a la primera hoja , por lo que Excel abre esto como la primera hoja
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


  // Redirigir la salida al navegador web de un cliente ( Excel5 )
  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Reporte de Cuestionarios.xls"');
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
  // Si usted está sirviendo a IE 9 , a continuación, puede ser necesaria la siguiente
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

  // Si usted está sirviendo a IE a través de SSL , a continuación, puede ser necesaria la 
  siguiente
  header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
  header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
  header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
  header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

 $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
 $objWriter->save('php://output');
 exit;

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Una vez tienes todos los datos en variables o en strings, puedes usar este codigo PHP para generar el Excel en formato **.xls**

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".botonExcel").click(function(event) {
        $("#datos_a_enviar").val( $("<div>").append( $("#Exportar_a_Excel").eq(0).clone()).html());
        $("#FormularioExportacion").submit();
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'");
header("Content-Disposition: filename=File.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

echo $_POST['datos_a_enviar'];
?>
```

En el HTML, pon el la class del botón para descargar el Excel, **botonExcel**, al final del html pon este input

```
<input type="hidden" id="datos_a_enviar" name="datos_a_enviar" />
```

Avísame si te funciona :)

Comment: Debo de tener el javascript en el mismo archivo de php?

Comment: No, el JavaScript lo pones en el HTML. Al final del todo pones el input que te puse, y el boton que quieras usar para descargar el Excel, le pones la clase **botonExcel**. Si en el HTML tienes algun ```<form>```, ponle ```action="descargarExcel.php"```